# Tomcat Load Balancing

Tags: java, tomcat, apache2, load-balancing

I have created a load balancing scenario in my machine and the same works fine. However, I am stuck at one simple issue and request help on the same.

I have two tomcat workers - worker1 and worker2.
I also have a loadbalancer called balancer. 
workers.properties file has been created as follows -

- workers.tomcat_home="MyTomcatDirectory"
- workers.java_home="MyJDKDirectory"
- worker.list=tomcat1,tomcat2
- worker.list=balancer
- worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
- worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
- worker.tomcat1.port=8009
- worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=1
- worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
- worker.tomcat2.host=localhost
- worker.tomcat2.port=8019
- worker.tomcat2.lbfactor=1
- worker.balancer.type=lb
- worker.balancer.balance_workers=tomcat1,tomcat2
- worker.balancer.method=B`

Now, I have a webapp say ***webapp1*** which is used by endusers extensively. I hence want that all the user requests for ***webapp1*** should be handled by worker1. For this I have added the below lines in httpd.conf file in my apache's conf dir -

- JkMount / balancer
- JkMount /* balancer
- JkMount /webapp1 worker1
- JkMount /webapp1/* worker1

This works fine as well. The only problem here is that if tomcat1 (worker1) is down, the balancer doesn't direct the request for webapp1 to tomcat2 (worker2). How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: Should  you set the load balancing type as round robin or something?

Comment: I have defined the worker called balancer of type lb. Balancer should take care of the roundrobin thing by itself. And it does so as well. The only problem is I have used JkMount to direct URLs referring to webapp1 to worker1. But when worker1 is down, the request is not redirected to worker2 and hence the EndUser receives an error stating "Service Unavailable - The server is temporarily unable to service your request due to maintenance downtime or capacity problems. Please try again later". Please help

Comment: You'd be far better off asking this at serverfault.com.

Answer (score 1):

If you want requests to go to worker 1 by default and then to worker 2 if and only if worker 1 fails you'll need to set up a second lb worker (call it lb2) with two workers (tomcat1b and tomcat2b) and use the distance parameter to give tomcat2b a larger distance than tomact1b. That will cause tomcat1b to be used in preference to tomcat2b unless tomcat1b fails.

See the workers.properties docs for more info:
http://tomcat.apache.org/connectors-doc/reference/workers.html

BTW you have tomcat1 in your workers.properties but worker1 in your JKMount. That won't work.

Comment: Hi Mark, 

You are right about the JkMount directive, I, by mistake, happen to mention worker1 over there when it should have been tomcat1.
However,

Comment: Hi Mark, 

You are right about the JkMount directive, I, by mistake, happen to mention worker1 over there when it should have been tomcat1.

But about the actual problem... Perhaps I wasn't clear in explaining the issue. I have 10 WebApps deployed on each of these tomcats. Out of these, webapp1 is used extensively by endusers. I hence want that requests for webapp1 should be taken care by tomcat1 by default. However, the traffic should be divided in the ratio of 1:1 (this is mentioned via lbfactor parameter in workers.properties file).

Comment: This means that 10 requests for webapp1 should be handled by tomcat1. Also, if at the same time, there are 10 requests for other webapps, they shud be handled by tomcat2. But if tomcat1 goes down, the requests for webapp1 shud be taken care by tomcat2.

Comment: Distance would simply set more preferred worker for a load balancer. If I use it for my scenario, tomcat1 would handle all requests at the start (including those that are not meant for webapp1) till it goes down.